# Jquery not working in this code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>FillForm</title>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
         <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[            
             function farax() {                
                 alert($('#txt_name').val());
                 return false;
             }
        ]]></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <form action="DisplayCustomer" method="post">
            <span> Enter customer id :- </span> <input type="text" name="Id" id="txt_name" /> <br            />
            <span> Enter customer code :-  </span> <input type="text" name="CustomerCode" /><br />
            <span> Enter customer Amount :-  </span> <input type="text" name="Amount" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" onclick="return farax(); " />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

The code above does not get the value inside the javascript function. What am i doing wrong here? This is a View in a ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I have not added any master pages. I tried using the same code inside a normal ASP.NET application and it worked fine but this seems to be skipping the javascript function altogather. Perhaps the jQuery is not loading properly. I have checked the path to see if it was faulty but that is also correct.

Comment: Is that an ASP textbox, or just a standard `input`?

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Change `onclick="return farax(); "` to just `onclick="farax()"`

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: they're returning to prevent the form submit from proceeding. It's either `return function();` with `function` returning `false`, or `function(); return false;`

Comment: @Farax: [I don't see a problem](http://jsfiddle.net/HeYDq/)?

Comment: Created a jsFiddle, and as soon as this click handler uses a function it doesnt work.  Strange.  Fiddle Linked to question.  
http://jsfiddle.net/v2gW5/

Comment: Nevermind, it all works fine.  I had to change the js wrapper type in the settings to make jsFiddle work.

Comment: @Steve: does it work? how?

Comment: Still doesnt work. When i place an alert with a string, it still doesnt work unless I remove the reference to JQuery. Only then it shows the alert otherwise it just gives me a reference error telling me that it cant find the function 'farax'

Comment: @Brad: it is interesting. I have no clue why it does not work locally! Still searching though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The odd thing was that it changing the JQuery version to 1.7 resolved my issue.  I would be happy if someone can shed more light on the issue !

Thanks!

Comment: Did the file jquery-1.7.1.min.js exist in the scripts directory?

Comment: Yes it did. That was the first thing I checked when I realized it was not properly loading

Answer (score 2):

Test this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">           
     function farax() {                
        alert($('#txt_name').val());
        return false;
     }
</script>
```

And :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" onclick="console.log(farax());" />
```

You have to see "false" in your debugger console (maybe, check if jQuery is loaded correctly i "scripts" or put `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`).

Comment: Check my answer. I am confused how changing the version number impacted this

Answer (score 0):

first, please ensure you know how to debug Javascript in browsers, in IE10/Chrome, press F12 to start debugger, and then you will find script error in console output, also you can debug the code step by step, in firefox, you can install Firebug, it's famous and powerful tool for script debugging.

then, if you get the specified error, that should be easy to fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, I do know that but again, the only info I am getting is that it is not finding the javascript function. Now this only happens when I have that line which includes the JQuery. Removing it makes the javascript function available

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" onclick="return farax(); " />
```

Change the type to type="button".

Comment: by submit form go to submit action after click action on button

Comment: It will not continue past the 'click' handler if false is returned.